# Как сделать несколько срезов в строке?

Tags: python, строки, list

Есть строка `n="√(9)-√(4)+5"`, и мне надо добавить в список числа, которые находятся в скобках (9,4). Все что находиться под циклом while,идет на другом уровне.

В данном коде при первом прохождении цикла все работает как надо, но при втором - все ломается, и место `4` выводится `-√(4`

```
n = "√(9)-√(4)"
i = 0
while i < 2:
    z = n[n.find("(") + 1:]
    final_sr = z.split(")")[i]
    print(final_sr)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

можно так попробовать

```
import re

n = "√(9)-√(14)+5"

res = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', n)))
```

`r'\((\d+)\)'` означает, что в строке будут искаться подстроки, которые описываются шаблоном `(цифры)`

`\d` означает, что ищется цифра (одна)

`\d+` означает, что будет искаться любое кол-во цифр

`\(\)` означает, что искаться будет внутри круглых скобок (поскольку круглые скобки в шаблонах выполняют служебную роль, то скобки как символы должны экранироваться

`()` означает, что мы ищем то, что находится в скобках (в нашем случае `\d+`, т.е. цифры), если в шаблоне не указать скобки, то будет искаться то, что совпадает с шаблоном, т.е. в нашем случае вместо `9` и `14` будет найдено `(9)` и `(14)`

ну и треш-вариант:

```
res = []

for obj in n.split(')'):
    data = obj.split('(')
    if len(data) > 1:
        res.append(int(data[-1]))
```

и однострочный треш-вариант:

```
res = [int(obj.split('(')[-1]) for obj in n.split(')') if len(obj.split('(')) > 1]
```

Comment: Где ты всему этому научился?

Comment: обычный самоучка :)

Comment: @Zhihar А ну давай расписывай шаблон re. Объяснять нужно народу. Должны "научаться" Regex.

Comment: А если будут float? Давай точку в шаблон. @Zhihar

Comment: ну с float тогда надо еще добавлять и `+-.e`, а потом еще и проверять, а точно ли число вытащили

Comment: @A_Vaclav, вот шаблон для целых и вещественных чисел в скобках: `re.findall(r"\((-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?)\)", text)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

как вариант методом `isdigit()` проверять, является ли символ цифрой. Ну а далее проверять соседние с ним символы, и если это скобка, или другая цифра - добавлять в подстроку, которую потом добавлять в список.